# QML Listview and c++: ReferenceError Model not defined

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I want to display my C++ class as a `ListView` in QML. I have an empty vector, which will later be filled:

```
QList<QObject*> _myList;
```

and set the context

```
QQmlContext *ctxt = _eng->rootContext();
ctxt->setContextProperty("modelName",QVariant::fromValue(_myList));
```

In the qml file I have

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    model: modelName
    delegate: myDelegate {}
}
```

But when starting the application I get the following error

```
qrc:/screen2.qml:252: ReferenceError: modelName is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? Strangly, the error does not prevent the list from being correctly displayed once it is filled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call `setContextProperty` before loading your QML file.

When you load your QML file, the engine evaluates its bindings, since you haven't yet set the context property for `modelName`, it outputs a warning.
When you set it afterwards, this binding is reevaluated and that's why the list is eventually correctly displayed in your case.